# Accessing two list elements at a time with enumerate

Tags: list, python-2.7, for-loop, range, enumerate

```
data = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff', 'ggg', 'hhh', 'iii', 'jjj']
```

This works exactly the way I want it to work.

```
i = 0
print
for i in range(len(data) - 1):
    print data[i] + ' ' + data[i + 1]
```

The below code does not work. Is there a way to make it work with `enumerate` or is the above solution the simplest/best way?

```
print
for i, d in enumerate(data):
    print d + ' ' + d[i + 1] # IndexError: string index out of range
```

Or is there another way to access two elements at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `enumerate` function, the `i` represents the index position of the list elements and `d` represents the value of the element present at the `i` th index position. So, when you are doing `d[i+1]` , you are slicing `d` variable.

When the value of `i` equals the last element of `data` variable in the `enumerate` block, accessing the `i+1`th element in `data i.e., data[i+1]` will throw an index error (since `i+1` th element does not exist in `data` ) . Since, you want to use both `i` and `i+1` elements simultaneously, using `enumerate` alone may not solve the problem completely. If you are keen on using it, you have to change your code to

```
for i,d in enumerate(data):
    if i < (len(data) - 1):
        print d + ' ' + data[i+1]
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm still trying to wrap my head around as to why it is `data[i+1]` instead of `d[i+1]`, but I'll get there.